# Process cannot be found

Tags: sockets, pid

I'm currently working on a socket application and it appears that my code doesn't end the connection between the sockets and causes an error: `bind failed with error: 10048`.

I then wanted to shut down the process associated to this link using the 'taskkill /F /PID ....' command with the PID I found but the process cannot be found. Did I do something wrong here?

Here are the terminal commmands I used:

```
PS C:\Users\user> netstat  -ano  |  findstr  8888
TCP    127.0.0.1:8888         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11112
PS C:\Users\user> taskkill  /F  /PID  11112
Erreur : le processus "11112" est introuvable. **the process cannot be found**
```

It is also impossible to locate the process in the task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Error 10048 is WSAEADDRINUSE, meaning the IP/port you are trying to bind to is still in use. Even though you shutdown a previous process that was using the IP/port, the OS itself is likely still holding the IP/port open and hasn't released it for reuse yet. By default, the OS internally holds onto a closed IP/port for an extra period of time to ensure any pending data for that IP/port gets flushed from the network. To work around that, you can enable the SO_REUSEADDR option on your listening sockets before binding them. Or, you can turn off a socket's SO_LINGER option before closing it.